# Possible conflict with jquery libraries

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I made a wp plugin which makes online reservations for rent a car but I tested it locally with a different wp theme and it worked fine! but when I installed it in this web site for some reason the jquery functions dont work! when I press the fortsetzen button it wont open the other step (its a form with 4 steps). I think it is because of the other jquery functions or libraries that the theme uses, I am frustrated I dont know what is causing this! Any ideas?

Comment: you have at least 3 versions of jQuery loading in page....this is such a common wordpress problem and there are tons of posts all over the net and this site about this. Use a browser console to chase down errors after reading WP docs for proper way to integrate jQuery

Comment: yeah I figured it out because I saw two versions of jquery, is there any way to force the scripts of my plugin to load at the end of all other plugins, do you think it will cause other problems?

Comment: yes read wp_enqueue docs. Your plugin files are not likely any source of problem. Then use browser console to chase errors

Comment: @cale_b thank for helping me. I am going to try not to load 3 different versions of jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using this: add_action('wp_print_styles', 'scripts'); now it works because It loads the scripts and the end but yet I have to fix the issues with other plugins and theme. Thank you all.

Comment: Try to use a different hook. The normal one: 'wp_enqueue_scripts' like this:

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','scripts'); Also, change the name of your function from 'scripts' to something else like 'my_theme_name_scripts'. And now, you're probably loading even more files hehe.
Anyways, if it works, leave it this way. You should NOT use wp_print_styles hook to load scripts.

But it's nice that's working again. It's a good start! ;)

Comment: I think for now I am going to use it this way and now I check if we are on the page where the plugin is used because I dont really have time to fix what the theme developer messed up by loading 2 different jquery libraries! thank you anyway for the tips I really appreciate your effort and the time you invested by helping me to solve this problem ;)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you're using to avoid conflicts but you can always use this snippet to avoid that:

```
(function($){

//Your code goes here

}(jQuery));
```

Also, be sure to load your scripts using [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function. And don't forget WP usually loads jQuery by default. Don't do it again unnecessarily.

Another edit: you [should NOT](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_styles) be using the wp_print_styles hook to load your scripts. The codex says on the link above: "wp_print_styles should not be used to enqueue styles or scripts on the front page. Use wp_enqueue_scripts instead." If it says so, you should be obedient =P

One last thing:  Please notice that wp_enqueue_script() accepts one last argument ($in_footer), a boolean, true or false, to tell WP where you want to load your scripts (header or footer). True loads on footer. By default it's set to false while you probably need to load your custom scripts and plugins on your footer, so you should set that to TRUE.

Comment: I use this: 

$(document).ready(function(){
});

Isn't it enough?

Comment: Nope, it's not enough. The '$' may still conflict with other plugins.
Change "$(document).ready(function(){" & "});" WITH "(function($){" & "}(jQuery));"

Comment: So it 'may' be what @caleb_b is pointing out. And double check your code, see if it's running using something like "alert('working');" inside your files and parts of your file do debug it.

Answer (score 3):

Do not include jQuery in your plugin folder.

Rather, load the jQuery that ships with WP through the WordPress built-in function wp_enqueue_script.

This will load the jQuery that ships with WordPress, and will prevent multiple instances of the same script (which you have) from being loaded.

Check the documentation [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for how to use it, and the long list of "built-in" scripts that you can load.

You can load jQuery, **without** including it in your plugin files, by using this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

You can also load jQuery ui, as well as draggable, droppable, and many others.  Look at the documentation to see that doing this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui');
```

will load jQuery ui core.

**Edit: **
Also, use Firefox, and install and use Firebug.  With Firebug, I am able to quickly see this error on your site:

*TypeError: $(...).inputfocus is not a function*

Line 16

Which tells me that in your plugin jQuery, you're trying to use jQuery by accessing the `$` function.  Within WP, you must use jQuery in a way that does not rely on the `$` function.  Either call jQuery with `jQuery(...)`, or else use it in some form of [compatibility mode](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries):

Comment: yes I am the wp_enqueue_script function, like this:

if($pagenow != 'wp-login.php' && !is_admin()) {
wp_enqueue_style('my-style', '/wp-content/plugins/rent-a-car/css/rent_a_car_style.css');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-min','/wp-content/plugins/rent-a-car/js/jquery.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-min','/wp-content/plugins/rent-a-car/js/jquery-ui-min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('inputfocus','/wp-content/plugins/rent-a-car/js/jquery.inputfocus-0.9.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-main','/wp-content/plugins/rent-a-car/js/jquery.main.js');
}

Comment: Right.  But you're loading YOUR own jquery.  Don't do that.  Look down the documentation, and you'll see you can use wp_enqueue_script('jquery'), and it will load the same jQuery that ships with WP.  If all WP developers did this (which they should), then there would ever only be a single instance of jQuery being loaded, which will prevent version issues, "bloat" from extra files being loaded, etc.

Comment: Yeah I tried wp_enqueue_script('jquery') and removed the jquery file but it doesnt work even locally. I will try to remove it completely and maybe it will work with other jquery library loaded by other plugins and see if it works.

Comment: Nope.  That's a mistake.  Do this: 1) Use the wp_enqueue_script('jquery')  - then 2) View source.  Is the jQuery being loaded?  If so, then you have OTHER issues in your javascript - not the loading of jQuery.

Comment: And he's probably using a Theme or something that's already loading jQuery for him. Inside his functions.php he probably don't need to load jQuery using wp_enqueue_script.

Comment: @7th - worse than that, he's using a theme that's loading it *from within the theme*, rather than the core WP jQuery.

Comment: I tried wp_enqueue_script('jquery') and it loads but it doesnt work, looks like I need to load the jquery.min.js and it is version: v1.4.4, then it works.

Comment: You're on the wrong track.  You need to fix this properly.  Read my edits, load jQuery the right way, and fix the other script errors.  Also, read @7th's answer.  He's completely correct, also.  FINALLY, get Firefox and Firebug, and learn to use it.  It will help you tremendously in troubleshooting script issues.

Comment: @cale_b - yes, and he got tons of js files loading. So many server requests. Solving this problem is only the beginning. Anyways, I do hope he gets this problem solved and after that, some others too ;)